# Typescript generic autocompletion when using lookup keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to have a type which will map a key into the corresponding data type for autocompletion.

```
type A = {
  key: "A";
  data: {
    a: number;
  }
}

type B = {
  key: "B";
  data: {
    b: number;
    c: string;
  }
}

type MyTypes = A | B
```

Now if I want to use them in a function like this the autocompletion works:

```
type DoSomethingOptions<T extends MyTypes> = T
function doSomething<T extends MyTypes>(options: DoSomethingOptions<T>) {}

doSomething({
  key: "A",
  data: {
  // only a is allowed
  }
})
```

But if I use lookup keys in the function options definition it stop working:

```
type DoSomethingOptions<T extends MyTypes> = {
  key: T["key"];
  props: T["data"];
}
function doSomething<T extends MyTypes>(options: DoSomethingOptions<T>) {}

doSomething({
  key: "A",
  props: {
  //a, b, c allowed for autocompletion, why?
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTypes` is a [`discriminated union`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) which consists of two very specific contracts

```
type A = {
  key: "A";
  data: {
    a: number;
  }
}

type B = {
  key: "B";
  data: {
    b: number;
    c: string;
  }
}
```

When you attempt to genericise with something like

```
type DoSomethingOptions<T extends MyTypes> = {
  key: T["key"];
  props: T["data"];
}
```

you lose access to the specific contracts and effectively get a union of the possible types for each key. This may be easier to visualise by listing out the [`indexed access type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#example-1) for each key of `MyTypes`:

```
type MyTypesKey = MyTypes["key"] // "A" | "B"
type MyTypesProps = MyTypes["data"]; // { a: number; } | { b: number; c: string; }
```

You can see therefore that `DoSomethingOptions` is akin to

```
type DoSomethingOptions2 = {
  key: "A" | "B";
  props: { a: number; } | { b: number; c: string; }
}
```

(Obviously not entirely accurate as this doesn't use the generic `T`)

When you attempt to use `DoSomethingOptions` as in your example

```
doSomething({
  key: "A",
  props: {
    // type?
  }
})
```

All that TypeScript can do is:

- Confirm that `key` is of type `"A" | "B"`
- Confirm that `props` is of type `{ a: number; } | { b: number; c: string; }`

In other words, you effectively unpack the contents of each specific contract and reapply them into a generic contract. You therefore lose all of the discriminatory capabilities